# Find the number of points between two "scatter with smooth lines" series

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I've attached an image that shows the scatter plot I've built in Excel. I need to know how many points are between the dashed line series and the solid line series just to the inside of the dashed line. This region is the "ideal" region of the plot.

[image]

[image]

Another note, all of the series on here are scatter plot data, with smooth lines as the type. See the second image for clarification on the region I am trying to count the points in.

Comment: Excel doesn't have such a functionality.  Even with a macro I'm not sure how it could be done. You probably use the wrong tool.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for the correct tool to use?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations (ie tools) are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0):

Find functions that approximate the boundaries of this region. Once you have functions, you can define the conditions for comparison needed to say if a point is inside or outside the region.

1. **Finding functions for boundaries.**
   You said your boundaries are based on scatter plot data. Presumably you already have these curves broken into pieces (i.e., different series). If so, you can use the `Add Trendline...` option in your chart (right-click a point in your boundary series to see this option). Choose the appropriate model and display the equation on the chart. You'll need to note these equations for each series so you can use them in step 2.

   If your boundary lines are not broken into appropriate series for this trend-fitting method, you'll have to do the regression work yourself in Excel. Explaining how to do this goes beyond the scope of the question and this site. I suggest googling how to perform regression analysis in Excel.
2. **Setting conditions.**
   Next to your data (for the green points in your example scatter plot), you'll want to add a column (or three) for formulas that tell whether the point is in the region. For your specific example, I'd use three columns: one to tell if the point is in the green region or L, another to tell if the point is in L, and a third to say if the point is in the first region but not the second.

   Your conditions will likely be dependent on the x-value of the datapoint. For your example, I would apply different conditions to x-values between 11.5 and 25.5 than for values greater than 25.5. Assuming your datapoints are defined in columns A (x-coordinate) and B (y-coordinate), here's a pseudo-formula you can use as a template.

   `=IF(A2<11.5,FALSE,IF(AND(A2>=11.5,A2<25.5),AND(B2<=[function for top boundary with A2 plugged in],B2>=function for lower boundary with A2 plugged in]),AND(B2<=[function for top boundary with A2 plugged in],B2>=0))`

   In the next column, you'll do the same, but with the boundaries for region L instead.

   In the last column, you'll need something like this to pick out the points that pass the first test but not the second:

   `=AND(C2,NOT(D2))`
3. **Count the TRUEs in column E.**